# Visual Studio 2010 Service Based Database With Users

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-connection, connection-string

I am sure this is a stupid question, but I was wondering how to create a Service Based Database (SQL Server DB) in Visual Studio 2010 with a user account.  I want this because I am creating a C# desktop application with a database back end.  When I created this project I created a Serviced Based Database in Visual Studio 2010 and the connection string uses my Windows Login for authentication.   Now that I have the application made and want to deploy it onto other machines, it cannot connect to the database because of the connection string.  So I was thinking that I can create a user account for the database and use that to connect.  Anyone know how to do this?  Thanks!!!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What does "it cannot connect to the database because of the connection string" mean?

Comment: Exactly what I said above...the connection string is using my windows login to authenticate instead of a database user acccount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I myself find the question very clear.  Obviously the instance of SQL is using windows authentication whereas Eric R. would like it to use SQL Login instead.  To accomplish this, I would install SQL Management Studio 2008 R2.  From there you can connect to your database instance.  You will want to right click on your server and go to Properties.  From there, in security you can tell it to use SQL Login.  You will also be able to create user accounts for your database inside of Management Studio.  Let me know if this helps...